# How to use SharePoint web services? (esp. authentication)

Tags: web-services, authentication

I am trying to access list information on MOSS 2007 using web services.

```
SppLists.ListsSoapClient proxy = new SurveyMerge.SppLists.ListsSoapClient();
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowNtlm = true;
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.None;
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = (System.Net.NetworkCredential)System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
XmlNode node = proxy.GetListCollection();
```

I get the following error message:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.
```

What must I do to authenticate the request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I thinnk I found the solution.

In app.config set security mode to TransportCredentialOnly and transport clientCredentialType to Ntlm. See snippet below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ListsSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
```

Comment: If you think this is the solution then mark it as the answer to the question.  That way everyone knows.

Comment: Charles - I wanted to but didn't have the rep to do it. I have done it now. Thanks to those who voted me up :-)